# How to Structure Newsletter Template content and style

Tags: email-templates, cms, newsletter

I was wondering if anyone could confirm whether my assumption of treating the template content area as the "body" bit and thus not including the html and head tags would be correct? or do I need to do include these tags and treat the area just like a blank doc?

Similarly, using the style tag in body is not valid html. Thus, if the head tag is automatically added then how can I include my style tag in there ?